# i am facing an error, "server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" after i transfered the folder where my site was hosted

Tags: php, xampp

This is the message I got "[Sat Nov 18 01:24:26.907439 2023] [ssl:warn] [pid 2244:tid 380] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" when i view my error log in xampp.
I am working on a login page.
I transferred the folder where my website was hosted from GitHub to my htdoc, before that it was working initially.
I try to uninstall my xampp and installed it again using the same setup but still didn't work.

Comment: Part of setting up SSL is creating a certificate that confirms to browsers that they are connected to the legitimate site. For that reason the certificate has the URL of your site coded into it. The right way to get that certificate set up will depend a lot on how and where you are hosting your site, but https://letsencrypt.org is a good place to get your certificate. But first check with your hosting provider if you have one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.